# ArcPy to include None geometries features

Tags: arcpy, geojson, null-geometry

I'm using ArcPy’s [JSON To Features function](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/conversion/json-to-features.htm) and saving the output featureclass within a gdb.
Some of the records in the input GeoJSON file don't have geometries but I want to keep them in the output. Using this method makes the function to ignore those records who don't have geometries.

How can I force the function to to include all the records in the GeoJSON file?

My Json file is an output from `geopandas.to_file(driver='GeoJSON')` .
Sample of my Json file (2 records):

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2039" }},
    "features":[{"type": "Feature","properties":{"a": 1000198, "b": 1, "c": 1997}, "geometry": null},
    {"type": "Feature","properties":{"a": 1000199, "b": 25, "c": 1994}, "geometry":{"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[195302.66, 661674.459999999962747], [195302.71720000001369, 661674.398399999947287], [195305.18, 661671.7548], [195305.1852, 661671.749599999981001], [195305.1904, 661671.743600000045262], [195307.7568, 661669.083600000012666 ]]}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your geojson file including correct and missing data?

Comment: You could use `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` to write your own load script with None geometries.

Comment: @Vince do you mean I can load all features from json file without using the funcion - JSON To Features   ?

Comment: Of course. It's more work, and probably slower, but there's usually multiple ways to load any given dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The [RFC 7946 - The GeoJSON Format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946) doesn't formally define empty geometries, the closest it gets is:

> GeoJSON processors MAY interpret Geometry objects with empty "coordinates" arrays as null objects.

*I think the phrase "null objects" is sloppy and confusing, and going with "MAY" only adds to the confusion, but that is the current standard and what we have to live with for now.*

What you have already found with [JSON To Features (Conversion) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/json-to-features.htm) is that a feature missing a geometry definition gets dropped from the import process.  The way to prevent this is to replace missing geometry definitions with geometry definitions with missing coordinates.  Esri then converts that feature into a record having NULL for the shape field.

Using the following GeoJSON file as an example,

```json
{ 
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[0.0, 10.0],[5.0, 15.0]] },
    "properties": { "Comment": "LineString" }
  } , {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": { "Comment": "Missing geometry" }
  } , {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [] },
    "properties": { "Comment": "LineString with no coordinates" }
  }]
}
```

one can see the behavior.

```py
>>> geojson = r"E:\tmp\geojson.json" # path to GeoJSON file
>>> arcpy.conversion.JSONToFeatures(geojson, "memory/geojson")
<Result 'memory\\geojson'>
>>> print(*arcpy.da.SearchCursor("memory/geojson",["SHAPE@", "Comment"]), sep="\n")
(<Polyline object at 0x1a2fbe2ed08[0x1a2f28b8930]>, 'LineString')
(None, 'LineString with no coordinates')
>>>
```

I would pre-process the GeoJSON file to replace missing geometry definitions with geometries with missing coordinates, and then run the JSON to Features tool

As an interesting side note, [AsShape - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/asshape.htm) handles GeoJSON geometries with missing coordinates as empty geometries, which is different than having NULL for the shape field.

```py
>>> geom = arcpy.AsShape({"type":"LineString","coordinates":[]})
>>> geom.WKT
'MULTILINESTRING EMPTY'
>>>
```